# "message exchanges" vs "messages exchanges"

Tags: grammaticality, compounds

I found a sentence in a paper which I believe to be wrong, I have a couple of questions:

Is it wrong? If not, which one is the correct form?

The sentence:

> ... these algorithms require successive control **messages exchanges**
>   between MB and GA ...

The part that I have emphasized confuses me.

Comment: The author probably intended "*messages exchanged*" (I.e. the final `s` was a typo for `d`, which is adjacent on a QWERTY keyboard), or "*message exchanges*" (singular "*message*").

Comment: "require successive control-message-exchanges between" OR "require successive control messages, to be exchanged between"

Comment: @Joe Are the `-`es needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> these algorithms require successive control messages exchanges between MB and GA

Should be

> these algorithms require successive control *message* exchanges between MB and GA

See the removal of the "*s*" from "*messages*".

This is because the "*exchanges*" is plural. If it was instead

> these algorithms require successive control messages between MB and GA

without the "*exchanges*", then it would be fine, but not both.

In fact you could equally have

> these algorithms require successive control exchanges between MB and GA

although that is less explicit that we are referring to messages.

Comment: Also _control messages (to be) exchanged between_ would be acceptable